# Save stdout and stderr of programs running under GNU Screen when you forgot to redirect it

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

Long story short:

I have launched a pipeline under a GNU Screen and instead of typing:

```
./pipeline.sh &> file.log
```

I typed:

```
./pipeline.sh
```

Logs from this pipeline are few thousand lines long and the pipeline itself need >10h to complete. Is there a way, I can still save it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's still in the GNU screen's buffer, you can:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>
- press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the command mode
- type `hardcopy -h file.log`

---

The default size of scrollback buffer in GNU screen is 1024 lines and you can check it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>
 <kbd>i</kbd>. It will be the first number after coordinates.

You can increase it (for future) in `.screenrc` file with `defscrollback` setting.

Comment: when I press Ctrl + a, there is "No other window" message popping. I don't know how much of a log is in buffer -  I entered copy mode and scrolled to the top until I could scroll no more - is it the whole content of a buffer?

Comment: You are in a screen session, press Ctrl+a and immediately get a "No other window" message? Sounds rather strange.

Comment: oh, now it worked. strange.